# The server farm account should not be used for other services

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2019, monitoring

I am getting this error message in my SharePoint 2019 TEST Environment. the Explanation says Farm, the account used for the SharePoint timer service and the central administration site, is highly privileged and should not be used for any other services on any machines in the server farm.  The following services were found to use this account:

1. SharePoint Search Host Controller Service(Windows Service)
2. SharePoint Server Search Service(Windows Service)
3. Distributed Cache Service(Windows Service).

I can certainly change the service account for these services from my farm account to a different one, but i am not sure what are the minimum priviledges required for a service/managed account to run these three services.. can any one please help with letting me know what minimum permissions are required for a service account to run 1) SharePoint Search Host Controller Service(Windows Service)
2) SharePoint Server Search Service(Windows Service)
3) Distributed Cache Service(Windows Service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/account-permissions-and-security-settings-in-sharepoint-server-2016#sharepoint-service-application-pool-account), the SharePoint Service Application Pool account must be a domain user account. This account must not be a member of the Administrators group on any computer in the server farm.

[image]

Also, the article lists recommendations for service accounts, you can have a refer on [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/account-permissions-and-security-settings-in-sharepoint-server-2016#service-account-recommendations-1).

Comment: thank u so much much appreciated